# Django Multiprocessing Error on Server But Works Fine on Localhost - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initializer'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, multiprocessing, init

When I Run my Django App on my computer it works fine. But when pushed to Ubuntu Server I am now getting the error.

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initializer'
```

Here is my View Code

```
def verifyt(request):
listi = get_listi()
print("verifyt",listi)
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4, initializer=django.setup) as executor:
    results = executor.map(wallet_verify, listi)
return HttpResponse("done")
```

Ive upgraded my python from 3.6.9 to 3.7.5 still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like its a Python Version error. I was Using 3.6.9 and then upgraded my Ubuntu Version to 20 that uses Python 3.8 and the error was gone.